# Find the sum of the maximum and minimum

Tags: contest-math, rational-functions

For a real number $x$ find the sum of the maximum and minimum.
$$y=\frac{x^2-2x-3}{2x^2+2x+1}$$
This is a sample question for a math competition. It seems like calculus would be used to solve this, but that sort of material shouldn't be on this competition.

Comment: What exactly is the question you have? And is this exactly how the problem was formulated? Does the problem ask to find $\min_x f(x)+\max_x f(x)$, where $f(x)$ equals your $y$ above?

Comment: @mathse This was the exact wording, yes. My question is what process I should use to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

$(2y-1)x^2+(2y+2)x+y+3=0 , \Delta=(2y+2)^2-4(2y-1)(y+3) \ge 0 \implies$

$4y^2+12y-16 \le 0 \iff (y+4)(y-1) \le0 \iff -4 \le y \le 1$

Comment: Can you explain it for a bit more? I'm kinda new to this too.